# Magento 2: Change page titles

Tags: magento2, page-title, head

How do I **change the page titles in the head section for each page**? I would like to show: 'page title | site name'

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Magento 2.2

For Magento 2.2 this is now in Content -> Design -> Configuration
Then click edit on either website, store or view.
Finally, go to the html head section and fill out Prefix or Suffix.

### Magento 2.1

In 2.1, this is now handled by UI component and it's located under **Content > Configuration >  > Other Settings** and then **HTML Head** section and here you can add a **Title suffix**

### Magento 2.0

To do that, you need to go to the back **Stores > Configuration > Design tab** then you open the **HTML Head** section and here you can add a **Title suffix**. In your case it would be `| site name`

[image]

Comment: This is now at **Content / Configuration / <store-view> / Other Settings** then open the **HTML Head** section

Comment: @oscarpas updated my answer, this indeed has changed in 2.1